# IIS Rewriting dosnt allow/breaks post requests

Tags: post, iis, url-rewriting, url-routing, aar

I have an IIS instance in front of my other non-iis web server hosting the site where the IIS is doing some AAR magic which is working good but for POST requests this dont seem to work for some reasons which mean any ajax calls by the application on the non IIS webserver end up broken. Any ideas on how to solve this? Below is the current rule setup.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="false" />
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="UrlWithPimRewrite" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="pim.*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(https?)://" />
                    </conditions>
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
                        <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
                    </serverVariables>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://localhost:1512/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="UrlWithoutPIM" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="/pim" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(https?)://" />
                    </conditions>
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
                        <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
                    </serverVariables>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://localhost:1512/pim/webaccess" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <outboundRules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="RestoreAcceptEncoding" preCondition="NeedsRestoringAcceptEncoding" enabled="true">
                    <match serverVariable="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" pattern="^(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="{HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="NeedsRestoringAcceptEncoding">
                        <add input="{HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" pattern=".+" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
        <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
        <tracing>
            <traceFailedRequests>
                <add path="*">
                    <traceAreas>
                        <add provider="ASP" verbosity="Verbose" />
                        <add provider="ISAPI Extension" verbosity="Verbose" />
                        <add provider="WWW Server" areas="Authentication,Security,Filter,StaticFile,CGI,Compression,Cache,RequestNotifications,Module,FastCGI,WebSocket" verbosity="Verbose" />
                    </traceAreas>
                    <failureDefinitions statusCodes="404" />
                </add>
            </traceFailedRequests>
        </tracing>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: first, try to run the failed request tracing in iis. did you try to make a post request without iis arr reverse proxy? make sure application work without arr reverse proxy. you could try some troubleshooting steps like Fiddler tracing, Winhttp tracing and netmon trace. also, check the back-end website's log when with Reverse Proxy.Is the post request reversed to the back-end website successfully? Does the back-end server handle the request correctly? Or the reverse proxy doesn't pass some data to the back-end website that causes the back-end website report error?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/chiranth/application-request-routing-part-2reverse-proxy-and-troubleshooting-arr-urlrewrite-issues